# Show an operator is continuous normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose that $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ and $(Y,\|\cdot\|)$ are normed vector spaces. Show that the map 
$$
F:\mathcal{L}(X,Y)\times X\to Y 
$$
defines as 
$$
F(T,f)=Tf.
$$

I know that (linear) operator is continuous iff it is bounded. However, I don't know if it's even linear. Any hint will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Although $F$ is not linear, it is not difficult to verify directly that it is continuous: If $(T_n,f_n)$ is a sequence in $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)\times X$ converging to $(T,f)$, then, we can write
$$T_nf_n-Tf=(T_nf_n-T_nf)+(T_nf-Tf)=T_n(f_n-f)+(T_n-T)f$$
Since $T_n$ converges in $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ it is bounded there, i.e. there exists a constant $M>0$ such that $\sup_n\|T_n\|\leq M$ for all $n$, hence
$$\|T_nf_n-Tf\|\leq M\|f_n-f\|+\|T_n-T\|\|f\|$$
and the r.h.s tends to zero, so that the l.h.s also tends to zero as $n\to\infty$, so that $F$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$||T_1f_1-T_2f_2||=||T_1f_1-T_1f_2+T_1f_2-T_2f_2||\le||T_1||\cdot||f_1-f_2||+||f_2||\cdot||T_1-T_2||.$$

That means, that for any $T_0\in{\cal L}(X,Y)$, any $f_0\in X$ and any $\varepsilon>0$ we know, that whenever we take $T\in{\cal L}(X,Y)$ and $f\in X$ so that $||T_0||\cdot||f_0-f||<\frac\varepsilon2$ and $(||f_0||+\varepsilon)||T_0-T||<\frac\varepsilon2$, then $$||T_0f_0-Tf||\le||T_0||\cdot||f_0-f||+||f||\cdot||T_0-T||<\frac\varepsilon2+(||f_0||+\varepsilon)||T_0-T||<\varepsilon.$$

Therefore $F$ is continuous.